# Mikrotik. Посмотреть в каком режиме подключился wifi-клиент (b, g или n)

Tags: wifi, роутер, mikrotik

Как можно посмотреть в Mikrotik'е в каком режиме подключился wifi-клиент - b, g или n? Использую Winbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Получите подробный список зарегистрированных беспроводных клиентов, выполнив следующую команду: `/interface wireless registration-table print stats`

Затем проанализируйте `tx-rate-set` для каждого клиента.

*Например клиенты `802.11b` поддерживают только скорости CCK.*

> CCK используется в беспроводных локальных сетях для достижения
> теоретической максимальной скорости передачи данных 11 Мбит/с.

UPD на основании комментария [Инопланетный гость](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/310487/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C):

если в значении `tx-rate-set` присутствует:

- `CCK` - поддержка `b`
- `OFDM` - поддержка `g`
- `HT` - поддержка `n`
- `VHTMCS` - поддержка `ac`

Comment: Спасибо! Еще дополнительно погуглил (на основании вашего ответа) и нашел, что если в значении "tx-rate-set" присутствует "CCK", значит есть поддержка "b"-режима, если присутствует "OFDM", то есть поддержка "g"-режима, если присутствует "HT", то есть поддержка "n"-режима, если присутствует "VHTMCS", то есть поддержка "ac"-режима. Это то, что нужно! Нашел, из-за кого у меня сеть сваливается по скорости, оказалась raspberry pi zero w в режиме "g" сидит. Осталось только понять, почему не в "n", т.к. в даташите вроде есть поддержка "n-режима".